# why while loops does not stop?

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops

I am trying to print "count" , when count is smaller than my input value , but when I give the input value for X, it loos forever.
Can anybody tell me why ?

```
count = 0 
x= raw_input()
while  count <x  :

    print (count )
    count +=1
```

Comment: what kind of values does `raw_input()` return? (to be more specific, *which* values does it normally return?) (are they always numbers?)

Comment: Change the assignment of `x` to `x = int(raw_input())`.  That way it will be an integer rather than a string.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the behaviour of the comparison operators (`<`, `>`, `==`, `!=`), you can check that they treat integers as being smaller than non-empty strings. `raw_input()` returns a string (rather than an integer as you expected), hence your `while` loops indefinitely. Just switch to `input()`:

```
count = 0 
x = input()
while  count < x:
    print(count)
    count += 1
```

Alternatively, you can use `int(raw_input())`, but I always use (and prefer) the former. All this is assuming you use Python **2**.

Answer (score 0):

Cast the input as an int so that the loop can increment it:

```
count = 0 
x = int(raw_input())
while  count <x  :

    print (count )
    count +=1
```